# How to create a USB CDC device. (I'm using stm32f103c8 black pill board) and I want to read the data through USB in my raspberry pi as a serial port

Tags: serial, softwareserial, raspberrypi, stm32

How to create a USB CDC device. (I'm using stm32f103c8 black pill board) and I want to read the data through USB in my raspberry pi as a serial port.

I am using a black pill to read RFID-rf522 to read a tag (SPI) and send it to raspberry pi through a USB (using DM and DP pins).

Quick responses are welcomed.

Comment: It depends on what the core provides. If it's like others, then `Serial.begin(115200);` or maybe `USBSerial.begin(115200);` will do it. Read the manual for the STM32F1 core on the website for that core.

Comment: Could it be that you might be better off just to use the [STMicro code](https://github.com/STMicroelectronics) for what you are doing?

Comment: if you use the core by STM select USB support in Tools menu

Answer (score 1):

You can use the one provided by generating it with [STMCubeMx](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stm32cubemx.html). This is going beyond arduino though. But it is highly feasible.